# yii CListView relation sorting

Tags: yii

Currently when i click on **sort by** in CListView generated table, it adds **MODEL_NAME_2** to the url

```
?page=1&sort=MODEL_NAME_2.cat.desc
```

is there a way to remove it? or maybe rename it to something else? Or is this just how Yii works?

here is my actionIndex() in my controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('MODEL_NAME_1', array(
        'id'=> '', 
        'criteria' => array(
            'with' => 'MODEL_NAME_2',
            'together'=>true, //specifies whether the query should be run using a join
        ),
        'sort'=>array(
               'defaultOrder'=>'MODEL_NAME_2.cat ASC',
                'attributes'=>array(
                    'MODEL_NAME_2.cat'=>array(
                        'asc'=>'MODEL_NAME_2.cat',
                        'desc'=>'MODEL_NAME_2.cat DESC',
                    ),
                  '*',
                )
        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageVar'=>'page'
        )
    ));

    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

in my view

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
                    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                    'itemView'=>'_view', // refers to the partial view named '_view'
                    'enableHistory'=> true,
                    'sortableAttributes' => array('MODEL_NAME_2.cat'=>'Make'),
                    'pagerCssClass' => 'pagination',
                    'loadingCssClass' => '', //remove loading icon
                    'template'=>'
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="pull-left">{summary}</div>
                                <div class="pull-right">{sorter}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">{items}</div>
                        </div>',

                ));
```

ideally i would like my url to look like this

```
mysite.com/bla/page/2/sort/cat/desc
```

basically using alot of `/` and no `?` or `&`

Comment: Please post your CListView definition to see how you declare the name for that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ListView definition change:

```
'sortableAttributes' => array('make'=>'Make'),
```

In your dataProvider

```
'sort'=>array(
               'defaultOrder'=>'MODEL_NAME_2.cat ASC',
                'attributes'=>array(
                    'make'=>array(
                        'asc'=>'MODEL_NAME_2.cat',
                        'desc'=>'MODEL_NAME_2.cat DESC',
                    ),
                  '*',
                )
        ),
```